# About compactness of simply ordered set with least upper bound property (Theorem 27.1 of Munkres)

Tags: general-topology, compactness, upper-lower-bounds, order-topology

I'm studying topology by Munkres.

**Theorem 27.1**:

> Let $X$ be a simply ordered set having the least upper bound property.
> In the order topology, each closed interval in $X$ is compact.

What makes me confused is that if I consider $X = (-\infty,0]$, it has the upper bound property for sure, and $X$ is a closed interval, because it's the complement of empty, which is open in any topology.

So, if I consider the collection $\mathcal{A} = \{(-n,0] \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\}$ as a covering of $X$, I can't find any finite subcollection of $\mathcal{A}$ that covers $X$. I'm supposing that $(-n,0]$ are open in $X$, or shouldn't I?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Munkres certainly meant closed bounded intervals (or his definition of interval already includes boundedness, e.g., closed interval may mean "Has the form $[a,b]$ for members $a$, $b$ of the space"), otherwise the result is simply false.

Comment: @MW I think you are right! But now what's the point of the least upper bound property? Since closed intervals are bounded by 2 sides, it already includes the least upper bound and greatest lower bound properties.

Comment: The least upper bound property does not apply only to closed intervals, it applies to all bounded subsets.

Comment: TY FIRE, before posting your question, didn't you read the first line of [Munkres' proof of this Theorem 27.1](https://faculty.fiu.edu/~draghici/pastcourses/Topology-F15/compactness-Munkres.pdf)? It is clear from it that what he calls "closed intervals" in $X$ are intervals of the form $[a,b]$ for $a,b\in X.$ As for your last comment, just follow the proof to see where the lub property is used.

Comment: @AnneBauval, Honestly I had just read the first paragraph of the proof before posting, and the wrong concept that I had in my mind was I assumed that the "closed intervals" and the closed sets were the same. Now, after reading the closed interval's definition in the order topology chapter, I noticed that was a dumb question. Thank you anyway.